# Setting up psycopg2 for the first time, how do you configure it for some test data bases?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This is my first time using PostgreSQL, I'm used to using MySQL where once you install MySQL server on Ubuntu for the first time, it'll ask you for a MySQL username and password. Once that's finished you can connect to it simply by providing:

```
MySQL Host: 127.0.0.1
Username: root
Password: 123pie
```

And from there you're ready to open up your favorite DB software like sequel pro and connect to it via SSH using the localhost IP of MySQL like shown above.

However right now my client is using PostgreSQL and so I need to learn how to set it up fast.

So far I've done this:

```
pip install psycopg2==2.4.5
```

Looks like this is just a library required for Django and Python to open up a PostgreSQL database. It doesn't look like something identical to MySQL Server.

Is installing PostgreSQL Server the next thing that I have to do? After I install that via the command line, is it exactly the same as setting up MySQL server?

I've never used PostgreSQL, I expect that it's very identical to using MySQL?

Comment: Postgres documentation is excellent, start here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-start.html

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice, detailed guide on the Ubuntu-specific setup for PostgreSQL on [the ubuntu community wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL). That should be your starting point.

For most applications it is sufficient to create a PostgreSQL user for the web server's username:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser www-data
```

then create a database owned by that user for the app to use:

```
sudo -u postgres createdb -O www-data test_django
```

and configure the app to connect with username `www-data` to the `test_django` database with no password. PostgreSQL on most distros, including Ubuntu, defaults to `peer` authentication where it requires you to have the same unix username as the postgres user you're connecting as, and doesn't require a password.

If the app forces you to supply a password and won't accept a blank one, or if you want the app to use a username different to the user that the web server runs as (i.e. to isolate multiple web apps from each other a bit), you need to [add an entry to `pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) specifying `md5` password authentication for that database/username combo - or just all users for all dbs.